# Imagettfbbox and imagettftext

Tags: php, imagettftext

Hey all i am wondering where i am missing the size of the textbox where the text is inside?

```
$img = imagecreatefromjpeg("Desert.jpg"); //http://s7.postimage.org/ceb440itn/Desert.jpg
$width = imagesx($img);
$height = imagesy($img);

$new_width = $width;
$new_height = $height;

$tmp_img = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
imagecopyresized($tmp_img, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);
// Create some colors
$black = imagecolorallocate($tmp_img, 65, 173, 196);
// Define Font
$font = 'ARIAL.TTF';
// The text to draw
$text = 'This is a test here here blah';
//font size
$size = 75;
// Compute size of text and get the x and y for centering the text into the image
$box = imagettfbbox( $size, 0, $font, $text );   
$x = 5;//($width - $box[2]) / 2 - 5;
$y = 75;//($height - $box[5]) / 2;

// Add some shadow to the text
imagettftext($tmp_img, $size, 0, $x+1, $y-1, $grey, $font, $text);

// Add the text
imagettftext($tmp_img, $size, 0, $x, $y, $black, $font, $text);

imagejpeg($tmp_img, "testing.jpg", 100);

imagedestroy($img);
imagedestroy($tmp_img);
```

The output image looks like this:

```
--------------------------
|This is a test here here|blah
|                        |
|                        |--Image
|                      --+----Inside image
|                        |
--------------------------
```

Notice it does not contain the word **blah** after **here** **within** the image itself.

This is what it should look like:

```
--------------------------
|This is a test here here|
|          blah          |
|                        |--Image
|                      --+----Inside image
|                        |
--------------------------
```

Where am i missing where it defines the size of the textbox?

Comment: I don't think you're missing anything - I just think the word-wrap would need to be done manually.  If I get a chance, I'll test that theory.

Comment: Please post a link to Desert.jpg, thanks.

Comment: @RayPaseur: http://s7.postimage.org/ceb440itn/Desert.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Using a minimum number of edits, I get an undefined var for $grey.  The output image is here  http://www.laprbass.com/RAY_junk/testing.jpg

So my next question is, eh?  I don't have the Arial font.  Is this what you're seeing?

```
$desert = 'http://s7.postimage.org/ceb440itn/Desert.jpg';

$img = imagecreatefromjpeg($desert); //http://s7.postimage.org/ceb440itn/Desert.jpg
$width = imagesx($img);
$height = imagesy($img);

$new_width = $width;
$new_height = $height;

$tmp_img = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
imagecopyresized($tmp_img, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);

// Create some colors
$black = imagecolorallocate($tmp_img, 65, 173, 196);

// Define Font
$font = 'ARIAL.TTF';
$font = 'fonts/verdana.ttf';

// The text to draw
$text = 'This is a test here here blah';

//font size
$size = 22;

// Compute size of text and get the x and y for centering the text into the image
$box = imagettfbbox( $size, 0, $font, $text );   
$x = 5;//($width - $box[2]) / 2 - 5;
$y = 75;//($height - $box[5]) / 2;

// Add some shadow to the text
imagettftext($tmp_img, $size, 0, $x+1, $y-1, $grey, $font, $text);

// Add the text
imagettftext($tmp_img, $size, 0, $x, $y, $black, $font, $text);

imagejpeg($tmp_img, "RAY_junk/testing.jpg", 100);

imagedestroy($img);
imagedestroy($tmp_img);
```

Comment: Sorry the font size should be 75. **$size = 75;** The font itself can be found on a windows computer in the **c:\windows\fonts** directory

Comment: And I just added stuff to the end of the text string.  PHP just made the string longer.  So I think you will have to word-wrap it yourself.

Comment: With the font size at 75, the text runs right off the screen.  What exactly are you aiming for here?

Comment: To have the text drop down. As you said, wrap.